# How to re-number biblatex citations

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am writing a long dissertation with lots of included files, and my supervisor has suggested numbering my citations in order of appearance rather than by author.  I understand that I can achieve this by changing from:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=ieee, citestyle=numeric-comp, sorting=nty, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
```

to

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=ieee, citestyle=numeric-comp, sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
```

However, when I recompile my document, the numbering doesn't change.  I have tried recompiling several times, and re-running biber.  I have eventually got the re-numbering to work by deleting all the aux files and all the other files automatically generated by the various latex tools, then recompiling from scratch.  This seems a bit awkward, and I'm scared of deleting the wrong thing by accident if I try it again when I'm working too late at night!

My question is, what is the "proper" way of re-numbering?  Should I have run a particular tool to force the numbers to be regenerated?  Or deleted a particular temporary file?

I have found several questions asking about changing the numbering style, but not anything that comments on how to actually apply the new style.

If it makes a difference, I am using TeXstudio with biber as the default bibliography tool, on top of TeX Live 2018.  I have seen some comments that latex has to be run twice after running biber.  I think TeXstudio does this anyway, and I tried manually recompiling too.

Comment: It is usually safe to delete auxiliary files. Texstudio does have a menu item for it, under "Tools" -> "Clean Auxiliary Files". Anyway, you should not have to do it normally, once you settled for `sorting=none`.

Comment: It is safe to delete auxiliary files. In this case you will want to look for `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf`, these three are the only files involved in sorting your bibliography and the `labelnumber` handling. Usually it should only be necessary to delete these files manually, if you changed your sorting scheme or some things went wrong on the last run. As soon as `sorting=none` is up and running with the LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX cycle there should normally be no need to delete the auxiliary files even if you rearrange citations and add new ones or drop others.

Comment: @gusbrs Do you want to type up a quick answer here? The official stance is certainly that deleting the aux files is safe and that it should not be necessary once `sorting=none` has settled in. If something else is going on here we would need to see code to investigate.

Comment: @moewe If you'd like to answer, please do so. At the moment I can't. But I could answer tomorrow, if you prefer that I do so.

Comment: @gusbrs I should really be going to bed now, so I can certainly wait until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no harm in deleting your auxiliary files, it is safe to do so. And it seems to be needed in this case. Furthermore, once the auxiliary files have been rebuilt with option `sorting=none` you should not have to worry of having to delete them again. The usual build cycle, `latex` -> `biber` -> `latex` (2x) will capture changes in your citations and references, as usual and expected.

As far as `biblatex` and `biber` are concerned, the relevant auxiliary files to deal with are `.aux`, `.bcf`, and `.bbl`.

Finally, TeXstudio offers an easy way to clean auxiliary files, with the menu entry under "Tools" -> "Clean auxiliary files".

Comment: Thanks. Deleting the auxiliary files fixed the problem.  Once `sorting=none` was working, I was then able to switch back and forth between that and `sorting=nty` with no need to delete anything; just the normal build cycle.  It's still useful to know about the "Clean auxiliary files" tool though.